# Mathjax - How to show preloader while math is typesetted?

Tags: math, tex, mathjax

How can i show a preloder like [loading...] until the Maths is typeset fully.Now the TeX code is shown as such until the typesetting is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    preview: ["[loading...]"]
  }
});
</script>
```

to use `[loading...]` instead of the TeX code as the preview.  See the [tex2jax configuration documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/options/tex2jax.html) for details.